# 'str.contains' not returning values in dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm cleaning some text data and I'm not able to locate rows containing certain strings. If I do a simple boolean, I get:

```
'<! [CDATA[! function( d,s, id){varjs, fjs=d. getElementsByTagName( s)[0],p= ^' in articles.loc[25111, 'content']

True
```

But if I select rows with that exact same string, I get an empty dataframe:

```
articles[articles['content'].str.contains('<! [CDATA[! function( d,s, id){varjs, fjs=d. getElementsByTagName( s)[0],p= ^')]

id  title   author  date    content year    month   publication category    digital section url stems
```

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think some values are read as regex, so need parameter `regex=False` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

```
s = '<! [CDATA[! function( d,s, id){varjs, fjs=d. getElementsByTagName( s)[0],p= ^'
articles[articles['content'].str.contains(s, regex=False)]
```